# dplyr: select by name and value at the same time

Tags: r, select, dplyr

(This question is probably a duplicate, but I can't find it being asked yet...)

Using `dplyr` techniques, how can I select columns from a `data.frame` by both names & values at the same time?  For example the following (which doesn't work):

```r
> data.frame(x=4, y=6, z=3) %>%
    select_if(matches('x') | mean(.) > 5)
Error: No tidyselect variables were registered
```

In base R, I would do something like this:

```r
> df <- data.frame(x=4, y=6, z=3)
> df[names(df) == 'x' | colMeans(df) > 5]
  x y
1 4 6
```

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55584714/how-to-select-columns-by-name-or-their-standard-deviation-simultaneously/

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, that indeed looks really close, though mine is a more distilled/abstract version of the question, and in the other Q they never really got to a nice clean answer like Andrew's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: **Using `dplyr` v1.0.0**:

```
data.frame(x=4, y=6, z=3) %>%
      select(matches("x"), where(~mean(.) > 5))
```

**Original answer**:
You could use `select` with a comma and `colMeans`

```
data.frame(x=4, y=6, z=3) %>%
  select(matches("x"), which(colMeans(.) > 5))
  x y
1 4 6
```

Comment: Nice! I did not even think to try it like that. Went directly to `bind_cols` :)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know (or forgot) that we could do `which(colMeans(.) > 5)` in a `select` clause.

It would be great if we could get rid of the `which`, I wonder why a logical vector of the same length as the number of columns isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `select_if` to extract the column names based on the condiiton and use that in `select` for those column names matching 'x'

```
data.frame(x=4, y=6, z=3) %>% 
     select(matches("x"), names(select_if(., ~ mean(.x) > 5)))
#  x y
#1 4 6
```

NOTE: Here we are using `select_if` as the OP wanted an answer specificially with that.  Otherwise, it can be done in many other ways

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't specifically looking for a way to use `select_if`, just `dplyr` techniques in general.

Comment: @KenWilliams  The `colMeans` technique is `base R`.  It is just a slight change in your original code with `base R`